# Quantitative dependency between queries

Tags: hive, presto

I have the following problem: my table1 has N positive samples, and it slowly grows over time. I want to select 10N negative samples from another table that is huge.
So it would be something like this:

```
WITH positive_samples AS (
  SELECT * FROM table1
), negative_samples AS (
  SELECT * FROM table2 LIMIT 100 
)
```

there are few problems with this query: it doesn't guarantee that I will have about 10 times more negative_samples than positive_samples, and it doesn't randomly select negative samples.

What would be a proper query in Hive or Presto to select these two sets?

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm go get your desired output in HIVE is this:

R1 = randomize Negative dataset
R2 = Assign row number to this R1
CP = Create a table containing one row and one column containing count of POSTIVIE rows. Call the column postive_cnt.
J = Take a a Cartesian Product of R2 and CP. 
FINAL = Select rows from J where row_number <= (positive_cnt * 10)

Actual query (tested on some datasets):

```
with 
pcount as ( select count(*) as positive_cnt from POSITIVE)
,
nrandom as( select * from NEGATIVE order by rand())
,
nrandom_row_num as ( select *, row_number() over() as row_number from nrandom )
,
jnd as (select * from nrandom_row_num, pcount)
select * from jnd
where row_number <= (positive_cnt * 10);
```